# Can't drag children with angular ui-sortable after converting the row content to directive

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui-sortable, angular-ui-sortable

I have list of rows and in each of this row there are cells (children). Both rows, and children can be dragged.

I achieved that with the following code:

```
<div ui-sortable ng-model="rows">

    <div ng-repeat="row in rows track by row.id" 
    class="row connector" 
    ui-sortable="sortOptions" 
    ng-model="row.children">
         <div>{{row.name}}</div>
        <div ng-repeat="child in row.children track by child.id"  class="col-3">
            <div class="widget">{{child.name}}</div>
        </div> 
    </div>

</div>
```

However, I wanted to move the row presentation and logic in it's own directive and controller. (controller is not relevant in this example so I skip the source code for it)

```
myapp.directive('block', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '' +
      '<div>{{row.name}}</div>' + 
        '<div ng-repeat="child in row.children track by child.id" class="col-3">' +
          '<div class="widget">{{child.name}}</div>' +
        '</div>',
    scope: {
      row: '='
    },
    link: function(scope) {
      console.log('row ', scope.row)
    }
  }
});
```

And changed the template to this:

```
<div ui-sortable ng-model="rows">

    <div ng-repeat="row in rows track by row.id" 
    class="row connector" 
    ui-sortable="sortOptions" 
    ng-model="row.children">

        <block row="row"></block>
    </div>

</div>
```

The problem is that I can't drag children anymore, only rows.
I can't find the reason why this broke.

Here is the full example: https://output.jsbin.com/zuxovod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yea, your HTML structure is not fine. Please check this **[runnable demo](https://output.jsbin.com/cecayazofo)**. You missed certain elements in your DOM structure to make it work fine. Also ensure that you use `replace: true` inside your directive to ensure a good DOM structure which is needed to make sortable run.

#### View

```
<div ui-sortable ng-model="rows">
  <div ng-repeat="row in rows track by row.id" 
       class="row connector"
       ng-model="row.children">
    <block row="row" sort-options="sortOptions"></block>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Directive:

```
myapp.directive('block', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true, 
    template: '<div><div>{{row.name}}</div>' + 
        '<div ui-sortable ng-model="row.children" class="connected"><div ng-repeat="child in row.children track by child.id" class="col-3">' +
          '<div class="widget">{{child.name}}</div>' +
        '</div></div></div>',
    scope: { 
      row: '=',
      sortOptions: '='
    },
    link: function(scope) {
      console.log('row ', scope.row)
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to use connectWith so that children can be dragged between rows too?

I tried to add `class="children"` and modified ui-sortable to `ui-sortable="childOptions"`  in the directive.

where `scope.childOptions = {connectWith: '.children'}`

I connected each list of 'children' to other 'children' list, which should make this possible, isn't it?

Comment: @tranq yea, I just updated my answer. Make sure that your connector container (`.connected`) has a minimal height + isset to `display:block`. -> https://output.jsbin.com/cecayazofo I pushed you a bit ;)